# Overriding deb dependencies

Tags: ros, opencv, installation, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
is there an easy way to manually override dependencies of a ros stack when installing it using the Ubuntu repository?

More specific: I'm trying to install ros-electric-openni-kinect which requires ros-electric-vision-opencv. The latter also wants to install the opencv libraries, which I already have installed (but manually built and therefore are not being tracked by dpkg).

Is there a way to workaround this issue or do I need to compile the ros stacks myself? Could that rise similar issues if something else depends on the vision-opencv stack?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11737/overriding-deb-dependencies/) by [moeter](https://answers.ros.org/users/1296/moeter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's definitely no "easy" solution.

If you want to use your custom compiled OpenCV in general anything that includes it or links against it will need to be built from source.  If the headers are unchanged and you have ABI compatibility you might get away with just switching it out.  But in general that will lead to very hard to debug errors.

From your statement you only need to compile the vision-opencv and openni-kinect stacks from source.  If there is anything else that you plan to use and depends on either of them it will also need to be recompiled.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0